# Radio Button vindo de Ajax não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá tenho um radio button q vem de ajax para calculo de frente não ele não funcionada para tirar o .attr({disabled: true}) de um button.

Se eu coloco direto na página ele funciona, mas quando ele carrega a partir de uma requisição ajax. Não.

**Inputs**

```
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" id="frete_radio" name="frete_radio" value="1"> 
  <span>a</span>
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" id="frete_radio" name="frete_radio" value="2"> 
  <span>b</span>
</label>
```

Se eu carrego os input:radio a partir do ajax ele não faz o codigo abaixo funcionar.

Mas se eu coloco direto na página ele funciona.

**Botão**

```
<button type="submit" id="btn-finalizar" disabled="disabled">
```

**Código:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("input[type=radio]").bind("click", function(){        
            if($("input[type=radio]:checked").val() == "frete_radio") {
                $("#btn-finalizar").attr({disabled: true});
            } else {
                $("#btn-finalizar").attr({disabled: false});
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se os elementos estão sendo inseridos no DOM após o bind do click, você precisa delegar o click de forma que o jquery consiga identificar o elemento clicado.

Você consegue fazer isso com o método [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) que está disponível no jQuery desde sua  versão 1.7

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $(document).on("click", "input[type=radio]", function(){        
            if($("input[type=radio]:checked").val() == "frete_radio") {
                $("#btn-finalizar").attr({disabled: true});
            } else {
                $("#btn-finalizar").attr({disabled: false});
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Em versões anteriores a 1.7 você consegue obter o mesmo resultado com o método [.delegate()](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/#delegate-selector-eventType-handler) que está disponível desde a versão 1.4.2 e está depreciado desde a versão 3.0

Em versões anteriores a 1.4.2 o mesmo resultado pode ser obtido com o método [.live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/#live-events-handler) que está disponível desde a versão 1.3 e foi depreciado na versão 1.7 e removido do core na versão 1.9.